# Django Template - filtering content

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I have two models - "Products" and "Categories", and every product may be added to existing category.
I am trying to find a way to render page with products, filtered by category.
Currently I did it for every category by manualy filtering it in template:

```
{% for instance in object_list %}
    {% if instance.category.categoryname == "Statues" %}
        {{ instance.name }}
        {{ instance.description }}
        {{ instance.price }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I have same template for every category ("Paintings", "Jewelry" etc) and changed condition in each template. URL "../Statues" leads to prexisting template

Is there any way to do it easier?
I would like condtition     *{% if instance.category.categoryname == "Statues" %}* to be imported from URL. So when you access "../Jewelry" - template would import "Jewelry" from URL and filter content accordingly.

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    categoryname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    #To make in name, not objXXX
    def __str__(self):
        return self.categoryname

class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='static/photos', default='http://placehold.it/700x400')
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    #To make in name, not objXXX
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('<str:categoryname>', category_filter)
]
```

**view.py**

```
def category_filter(request, categoryname):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    context = {"object_list": queryset}
    return render(request, "category_filter.html", context)
```

category choice template:

```
{% for instance in category_list %}

<a href="{{ instance.categoryname }}" class="list-group-item">{{ instance.categoryname }}</a>

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be too simple answer ...you can apply filter in your views and send query set based on that:

```
def category_filter(request, categoryname):
    category=Category.objects.get(categoryname=categoryname)   
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(category=category)
    context = {"product_list": queryset}
    return render(request, "category_filter.html", context)
```